# Document format conversion to text

Tags: java

what i am looking for is a text conversion library that could convert the format of the word file,pdfs

but retain their formatting structure after text conversion the table structure is lost and the document becomes distorted

for instance

name emailid phonenumber are in a table and form a row in

after conversion these come in separate lines like

name

emailid

phonenumber

i want these to come as name emailid phonenumber

currently I am using apache tikka and it uses apache poi how can i achieve this

can i parse the msword document element by element if yes please share a example

regards

Rajat

Comment: Exactly how would you like the data to be 'formatted' if you remove all formatting by virtue of converting it to a .txt file?

Comment: Please explain clearly what your are looking and requirement.Also let us know what efforts you put on the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can read content of your .doc .dox by using [APACHE POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html)   and pdf [PDF READ](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=101&)

Then you can write that content to text file